# Is there a way by which I can run SlidesApp.openById() from within onOpen function of apps script in google slides?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

```
function onOpen() {
    // Add a custom menu to the google slide.
    let menu = SlidesApp.getUi().createMenu('EditAddon')
    menu.addItem('Edit Text', 'editText')
    menu.addToUi();
}
```

this is my onOpen function and this works fine.
But when I change it to something like the code below,

```
function onOpen() {
    // Add a custom menu to the google slide.
    let menu = SlidesApp.getUi().createMenu('EditAddon')
    menu.addItem('Edit Text', 'editText')
    menu.addToUi();
    const slides = SlidesApp.openById("myslideidgoeshere").getSlides();
}
```

I get an error saying that,"*Exception: You do not have permission to call SlidesApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations at onOpen*"

I had gone through few references and saw that I need to add permission in the manifest file. And, did that too. Below code is from my manifest file(appsscript.json).

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.readonly",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations"
                 ],
   "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
   "dependencies": {},
   "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
   "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

But still I face the same issue.
What I need is, when a user installs my add-on he should be redirected to googleslides with the so called presentation open in it. Is there anyone who can help me out of this please?

Comment: You cannot do that with a simple `onOpen` trigger. But anyway, I'm not sure I understand `when a user installs my add-on he should be redirected to googleslides with the so called presentation open in it`. `openById` doesn't actually open the presentation in the browser, are you aware of this? How do you want to be redirected? What you're trying to accomplish is not clear for me, can you provide more information?

Comment: @lamblichus My ultimate target is to display a "User Guide for the add-on" as a GSlide presentation when the user completes the add-on installation. I was using the openById function only to pull the particular presentation from my GDrive with the so called slideId into a variable so that, I could later loop that variable and display the slide content using  SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().insertSlide() function. So I would like to know if there is any other workaround for it

Comment: Add-on `onOpen` triggers run in `AuthMode.NONE` or `LIMITED`, depending on whether the add-on is installed or also enabled for the document. In none of these modes you are allowed to call `SlidesApp.openById`. If I understand correctly, you just want to to call this once, when it is installed? If that's the case, I'd call `openById` inside `onInstall(e)`, which runs in `AuthMode.FULL`. I'm still not sure about the workflow you have in mind here, so I prefer not posting this as an answer yet.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to copy a slide from that specific presentation to the active one when the add-on is installed? What's the point of this? Why doing this _when installing the add-on_? Are you aware that add-ons can be installed without there being an active presentation?

Comment: Thankyou @lamblichus. What you said was absolutely right. I wanted a "how to use" context presentation to be open when the user first installs the add-on. So, as you said calling the openById in onInstall will do my work. Thankyou for making that clear

Comment: The main problem I see, as I said, is that it's possible to install an add-on without having an active presentation (you can install Slides add-ons [here](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/category/works-with-slides), for example), so if you want to use `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().insertSlide()` when the add-on is installed, that would fail. Of course you could tackle that by checking in the function whether there is an active presentation, but then the `onInstall` would not run in the future. Not sure if your question is answered by this?